# how can i set icon for fragment host in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here is my activity in which i set fragment tabs:

```
 private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bottom_tabs);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("key", "Simple");
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconxml)
            Fragment1.class, b);
```

iconxml.xml file

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false"
 android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icontab" />
```

my app crashes with this.. plz help

![exceptions][logcat outout]

Comment: Which line you got NPE??

Comment: mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconxml)
            Fragment1.class, b); this line

Comment: are you getting null pointer exception?

Comment: no...E/AndroidRuntime(8220): java.lang.StackOverflowError 01-06 13:56:16.709: E/AndroidRuntime(8220): at android.util.LongSparseArray.get(LongSparseArray.java:79) 01-06 13:56:16.709: E/AndroidRuntime(8220): at android.content.res.Resources.getCachedDrawable(Resources.java:1984) 01-06 13:56:16.709: E/AndroidRuntime(8220): at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1882) 01-06 13:56:16.709: E/AndroidRuntime(8220): at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconxml)
        Fragment1.class, b);
```

Comment: i tried, but when i keep string empty its displaying icon image,if i have text then its not working... no exceptions but icon not visible

Comment: what is your minimum and maximaum SDK version?

Comment: 8 and 15...and i am trying to run it on android device which has 4.03 version

Comment: Have you make custom layout for tab means...for text and Image

Answer (score 0):

Replace this to

```
   mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconxml) Fragment1.class, b);
```

this

```
   mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple",this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconxml)) Fragment1.class, b);
```

See there [TabHost.TabSpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html)

Comment: 01-06 13:56:16.709: E/AndroidRuntime(8220): java.lang.StackOverflowError
01-06 13:56:16.709: E/AndroidRuntime(8220):  at android.util.LongSparseArray.get(LongSparseArray.java:79)
01-06 13:56:16.709: E/AndroidRuntime(8220):  at android.content.res.Resources.getCachedDrawable(Resources.java:1984)
01-06 13:56:16.709: E/AndroidRuntime(8220):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1882)
01-06 13:56:16.709: E/AndroidRuntime(8220):  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)

Comment: I am working on other task But now follow this, you may got answer   http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-navigation-tabs-using-tabhost-and-fragments-in-android/   Or    http://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/

Answer (score 0):

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-navigation-tabs-using-tabhost-and-fragments-in-android/

i tried modyfing above example and finally solved my problem :)